# Enable/Disable Controls on selection of Radio using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visibility, disabled-control

I am trying to Enable/Disable certain controls depending upon the selection of Radio. it doesn't seem to be working.
I want the disabled text and radio fields to be enabled when yes radio is selected.
Please help!

ASP snippet

```
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="control-label">Whether any other children of the same family is studying in Primary/ Secondary Section of SVVHS</label><br />
                    <input type="radio" value="yes" id="chkRelatedStudentYes" runat="server" name="RelatedStudent" required="required"/> <label class="control-label">Yes</label><br />
                    <input type="radio" value="no" id="chkRelatedStudentNo" runat="server" name="RelatedStudent" required="required"/> <label class="control-label">No</label>
                 </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Name of the Student</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name of the Related Student" id="txtRelatedStudentName" runat="server" disabled="disabled" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Section</label><br />
                    <input type="radio" value="Primary" id="chkPrimary" runat="server" name="Section"  required="required" disabled="disabled"/> <label class="control-label">Primary</label><br />
                    <input type="radio" value="Secondary" id="chkSecondary" runat="server" name="Section"  required="required" disabled="disabled"/> <label class="control-label">Secondary</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Standard</label>
                    <input maxlength="12" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Standard of the Related Student" id="txtStandard" runat="server" disabled="disabled"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Division</label>
                    <input maxlength="12" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Division of the Related Student" id="txtDivision" runat="server" disabled="disabled"/>
                </div>
```

jquery snippet

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#chkRelatedStudentYes').click(function () {
                $('#txtRelatedStudentName').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#chkPrimary').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#chkSecondary').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#txtStandard').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#txtDivision').removeAttr("disabled");
            });
            $('#chkRelatedStudentNo').click(function () {
                $('#txtRelatedStudentName').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#chkPrimary').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#chkSecondary').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#txtStandard').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#txtDivision').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
</script>
```

Comment: just place an alert() on start of document. read and check weather this jquery is getting fired or not and revert

Comment: Yes. I got an alert. It is getting fired.Although I placed an alert inside the below script.. Didn't work on click

$("input[name=RelatedStudent]:radio").click(function() { 
        });

Comment: then code seems to be fine, i checked it in fiddle and every thing seems fine, did you tried the console, what error is it giving there

Comment: I am getting no error in console too..

Comment: just got my eye on this line  nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');. may be it is causing issue,

Comment: Tried commenting it out.. Still doesn't work..
i place an alert for click event of the radio.. no effects there too

Comment: I have found a solution for this issue. Find my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was.
The script wasn't able to find the element by ID or its NAME attribute.
I tried all the possible way to fire the script on click of the element and realized that it was working when i used -  $("input[type=radio]:radio")
and also using the class name - $(".form-control") I modified the script and used the below script and boom it worked

```
$("input[type=radio]:radio").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
        $(".form-control-disable").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'no') {
        $(".form-control-disable").attr("disabled", "disabled");       
            }
});
```

I used the following class for the text and radio controls that had to be disabled ".form-control-disable" and it worked.
I thank Abhi for his patience and help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi your way of triggering event is wrong

Please try this, here is complete code that should work

Note : Tested it

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name=RelatedStudent]:radio").click(function() { // attack a click event on all radio buttons with name 'radiogroup'


                if($(this).val() == 'yes') {//check which radio button is clicked 
                        $('#txtRelatedStudentName').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#chkPrimary').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#chkSecondary').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#txtStandard').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#txtDivision').removeAttr("disabled");
                } else if($(this).val() == 'no') {
                      $('#txtRelatedStudentName').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#chkPrimary').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#chkSecondary').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#txtStandard').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#txtDivision').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } 
        });
});
```

You can try it here https://jsfiddle.net/abhiyx/fgen1br9/

Comment: Please fill code acc. to your preference in the events

Comment: yes the code mentioned in the desc was present inside $(document).ready(function()...
still didn't work bro

Comment: i am not mentioning about document.ready, am saying about $("input[name=RelatedStudent]:radio").click(function(), wait let me get a fiddle for you

Comment: I tried this code too.. I don't know whats going wrong here..It still ain't working.

Comment: answer updated, please try the fiddle link and let me know if its works

Comment: This is weird..
I tried copying my whole page into fiddle and ran it.. 
It works perfectly fine.. yet doesn't work in my local environment..

Comment: is possible show me your code, are you importing jquery, and also try checking console may be you get some error there

Comment: I've Updated the question and added the code for the whole page.. If it helps.. :)

Comment: Hey Abhi thanks for your patience and help. I found a solution. Please find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery prop() method instead of removeAttr(). Try this -

```
$('#chkRelatedStudentYes').click(function () {
   $('#txtRelatedStudentName').prop("disabled", false);
   $('#chkPrimary').prop("disabled", false);
   $('#chkSecondary').prop("disabled", false);
   $('#txtStandard').prop("disabled", false);
   $('#txtDivision').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the html elements is rendered on the server, the IDs of the elements will change. 
While access the IDs in javascript, Please use as following:

```
$('#<%# chkRelatedStudentYes.ClientID%>').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for that. I will note this down!